# start bash with last exit code of 0

Tags: bash, visual-studio-code, msys2

When I start a new bash shell, if I run the command `echo $?` as the first thing, I get 1. How can I run bash with the "default" exit code being 0?

Context: I am running msys2 in a terminal window in VS Code. If I start msys2, and then realize I didn't need a shell now and just type `exit`, bash exits with 1, causing VS Code to pop up an annoying warning.

Comment: If you don't have ways to change init files, instead of typing `exit`, type `exit 0`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely something in your profile is failing and setting the status code to 1. Since status codes are overwritten by each process that runs, it'll probably be something towards the end.

Comment: It was this: `[[ "$-" != *i* ]] && return` in my `.bashrc`